# CDVPlugin class SocialSharing (pluginName: SocialSharing) does not exist

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

Social Sharing plugins working well in Android. But the same code shows the following error in iOS Device.

All the plugins are installed .

Error:

plugin com.skype.SkypeForiPad.sharingextension invalidated
2016-04-26 19:21:26.285 AiCura_App[id] SocialSharing app selected: (null)

Code :

```
   $scope.shareViaTwitter=function (title, source, link){
  window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaTwitter(title,
                                                  null /* img */,
                                                  link /* url */, 
                                                  source, 
                                                  function(errormsg){


        alertService.showAlert('You Have to install Twitter application to share this news')}
      //  alert("You Have to install Twitter application to share this news")}
                                                  );
 };
```

Comment: I have tried cordova build iOS too ... but dint work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute all ionic and cordova commands with sudo ... (Administrator privillage)

- sudo ionic plugin add [plugin-name]
- sudo cordova prepare ios
- etc ...

Comment: If you are having to run sudo on anything for cordova, your environment is improperly configured. Specifically your node directories permissions.

Comment: That's good and all but your environment is misconfigured if it requires sudo. Source from npm docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions